# Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) - Eclipse Application Uses Java 6

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osgi

I'm trying to run an Eclipse Java application on Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.3).

The bundles in the application require Java 7 and I have installed it.

EDIT: I should be clear that this is a packaged and downloaded Eclipse OSGi-based application, not one I've built locally.

The application keeps failing to launch.  It dumps me back to the OSGI console and generates a log which contains the following error for several OSGI bundles:

```
!SESSION 2013-12-06 08:10:23.406 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/jasonbarrett/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -console -keyring /Users/jasonbarrett/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY com.voxware.common.component 4 0 2013-12-06 08:10:24.314
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "com.voxware.common.component_1.0.0.201310160110 [10]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

The bundle wants Java 7 but as you can see, java.version=1.6.0_45.

Java 7 looks OK at the command line:

```
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ 

Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ 

Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ 

Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
    1.7.0_21, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_45-b06-451, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_45-b06-451, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_37-b06-434, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_37-b06-434, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I've tried setting the -vm switch in the launcher's .ini file to several locations where Java 7 might be, currently it's:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-console
-vmargs
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dbundles.configuration.location=../../../configuration
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

I've also tried:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

and

```
-vm
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

At the OSGI console, 'getprop' gives me the following:

```
eclipse.vm=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
eclipse.vmargs=-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dbundles.configuration.location=../../../configuration
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Djava.class.path=/Applications/Shark/Server-All/Shark-Server-All.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar

…

java.class.version=50.0
java.endorsed.dirs=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs=/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext
java.home=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/t9/n8g9424j5kv2577mmpyg767m0000gn/T/
java.library.path=.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version=1.6
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
java.vendor.url=http://www.apple.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.apple.com/
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.vm.vendor=Apple Inc.
java.vm.version=20.45-b01-451
```

No matter how I try to set up my environment for Java 7, the app launcher insists on using Java 6.  I read elsewhere that on the Mac, it effectively ignores the -vm switch and always sets the vm to:

```
eclipse.vm=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
```

On my system, this looks like:

```
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
total 64
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   27 Apr 22  2013 Classes -> Versions/CurrentJDK/Classes
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   28 Apr 22  2013 Commands -> Versions/CurrentJDK/Commands
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   27 Apr 22  2013 Frameworks -> Versions/Current/Frameworks
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   24 Mar  5  2013 Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   24 Apr 22  2013 Home -> Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   23 Apr 22  2013 JavaVM -> Versions/Current/JavaVM
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   29 Apr 22  2013 Libraries -> Versions/CurrentJDK/Libraries
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   26 Apr 22  2013 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Dec  4 14:02 Versions


Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  59 Dec  4 14:02 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/

Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1 Apr 22  2013 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current -> A
```

I was given to understand that Java 7 is installed in this 'A' directory, is that true?

Also, where does the eclipse application launcher get its 'java.home' from?  As you can see above, it's

```
java.home=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But that doesn't agree with my JAVA_HOME or /usr/libexec/java_home.

```
Jasons-MacBook-Pro:MacOS jasonbarrett$ which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Any ideas?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know this is very very late .. did you check the packaged application's Info.plist file, possibly in the app_name.app/Contents directory?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Eclipse `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` and see if you have a Java 7 JRE. Add Java 7 if it is missing. You can also select the check box to make the JRE the default.

In `Run > Run Configurations` choose the configuration for your application and on the first tab select the Java 7 JRE (or execution environment) in the Java Runtime Environment section.

Comment: Thanks, Greg.  In my local Eclipse, indeed the installed JRE appears correct.  I just tried to add a screen shot, but apparently I can't in a comment.  This is actually a packaged Eclipse OSGi application, I didn't build it locally and I'm running it from the command line, not through Eclipse, but it should have been built against Java 7.